# How to disable the Upload Tab when inserting an image in Opencart's CKEditor?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, opencart

After I upload an image via Upload tab > Upload, I get this error - apparently the filemanager is opened up in an iframe. Since I don't know how to fix this and I can upload images just fine from Image Info > Browse Server, how would I go about deleting/disabling the Upload tab?

I tried to comment out the last 3 lines but the upload tab still shows up:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    //filebrowserUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    //filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    //filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>'
});
```

I [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just paste this code before `CKEDITOR.replace` line:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name,
        dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if (dialogName === 'image') {
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('Upload');
    }
});
```

Comment: You Sir, are a life saver. Worked like a charm. Thank you!